# Metropolis-Hastings or other MCMC method with an unknown asymmetric proposal distribution?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

When working with the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, we can work with an asymmetric proposal density $g(x^\prime | x)$ provided we know the distribution in order to calculate the ratio $\frac{g(x|x^\prime)}{g(x^\prime | x)}$. We can use also utilize a process that proposes updates according to an unknown distribution, for example in Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, provided we know the distribution is symmetric so that we do not have to calculate the above ratio.

My question is: suppose I have a process that generates random states (independent of the previous state) with nonzero probability for each state, but I do not know the probabilities and hence cannot calculate $\frac{g(x|x^\prime)}{g(x^\prime | x)}$. Is there any MCMC algorithm I can use for sampling in this scenario?

Comment: Is this a job for Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)?

Comment: A sampling process that only guarantees nonzero probability is not much. E.g., any sampling from $\mathbb R$ has this probability for the normal distribution. Do you know anything else about this process?

Comment: @frank The process is discrete and samples from a distribution that is approximately uniform, but not uniform enough to not affect my outcomes.